# How to delete standalone attachments from couched via light couch?

Tags: couchdb

I am using light couch to store standalone attachments in my couch db documents. Is there any way to delete these standalone attachments without deleting the host document via lightcouch? java docs only talks about creating and updating them: http://www.lightcouch.org/lightcouch-guide.html#docs-api-attachment-standalone

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the attachment without the need to delete the host document

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/document/attachments.html#delete--db-docid-attname

... but it seems to be not implemented in the lightcouch library. Create an API call like

```
DELETE /dbname/doc_id/attachment_id?rev=doc_rev
```

If it works you can enhance the lightcouch library and contribute it.